# How to modify the title of remote debug url in CefSharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I made a browser using cefsharp in winform, the browser will show different content based on user's configuration. When open remote debug(http://localhost:9999), the url link always show the title `test page`. If I create two instances, I could not tell them apart.
How to modify the title in code? Is there any CefSharp configuration I can add to modify the title in remote debugging page?

```
[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9999/devtools/page/5D72AFB9FF36FE8389138F51ED9A9735",
   "id": "5D72AFB9FF36FE8389138F51ED9A9735",
   "title": "test page",
   "type": "page",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9999/devtools/page/5D72AFB9FF36FE8389138F51ED9A9735"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration option for modifying the `title` show in remote debugging. The `title` should exactly reflect the `<title>` of your web page. You need to give you pages unique titles if you want them to be distinguished in devtools.

You can execute JavaScript to change your web page title if needed (or simply change your html).